# How to escape special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, encoding

When I do `select * .. | mysql ... > /tmp/file` from a table with text, there are some problematic characters that prevent me from loading it to a different db using `copy` (postgres) or `load into` (mysql).
Character like tab, new line are translated automatically to `\n` and `\t`, but some of the problematic characters are escape `^[`, CR `^M`, `^U`,`^Z`,`^F`,`^H` and maybe other that I haven't seen before.

Usually I would just replace it like `echo "select * .." | mysql .. | sed 's/\r/\\r/g'`, but there are too many unknown chars there. So instead of replacing them after the select I would like a function that retrieve the text already escaped (I guess remove them is also fine).

How should I do it?

Comment: can you provide more content like the text you try to import and the table, the are to load into some more possibilities like ESCAPE

Comment: Execute `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` instead of simple SELECT.

Comment: Avoid shell scripts -- that just doubles the complexity.  Go through files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape all special char except NULL, new line and tab:

`select * .. | mysql ... | sed 's/[\x04-\x08\x0B-\x1F\x7F]/ /g' > /tmp/file`

useful link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc